How to connect an Azure Share to a Windows Drive Letter
I have a connection string to an Azure Storage Share which looks like this:
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https; 
AccountName=myaccount; 
AccountKey=xxx_LongEncryptedString_xxx; 
EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

Also, I have a Sharename like "MyShare". In C#, I connect like this:
ShareClient share = new ShareClient(connectionString, "MyShare");

Question: I would like to connect this share to a Drive in Windows (10 / 11 Pro) with Powershell or cmd. How can I do this?
EDIT: I cannot login to the Azure portal. I have only the information as shown above.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#using-an-azure-file-share-with-windows

@Arko Thanks, but I cannot login to the Azure portal. I have only the information as shown in the post above.

@askolotl Check the below answer.


How to connect an Azure Share to a Windows Drive Letter

You can use the below script to connect the Azure File Share to your windows with connection string using Powershell.
Script:
$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
$shareName = "share1"    # Replace with your Azure File Share name
$driveLetter = "Z"       # Desired drive letter


$connectionStringDict = @{}
$connectionString.Split(';') | ForEach-Object {
    $key, $value = $_ -split '=', 2
    $connectionStringDict[$key] = $value
}


$accountName = $connectionStringDict["AccountName"]
$accountKey = $connectionStringDict["AccountKey"]
$endpointSuffix = $connectionStringDict["EndpointSuffix"]
$fileSharePath = "\\$accountName.file.$endpointSuffix\$shareName"

# Test connectivity to port 445
Write-Host "Testing connectivity to $accountName.file.$endpointSuffix on port 445..."
$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "$accountName.file.$endpointSuffix" -Port 445

if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
    Write-Host "Connection successful! Proceeding with drive mapping..."
    
    # Save credentials for persistence
    Write-Host "Saving credentials..."
    cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"$accountName.file.$endpointSuffix`" /user:`"localhost\$accountName`" /pass:`"$accountKey`""
    
    # Map the drive
    Write-Host "Mapping drive $driveLetter to $fileSharePath..."
    New-PSDrive -Name $driveLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $fileSharePath -Persist
    
    Write-Host "Drive mapped successfully! You can access it as ${driveLetter}:"
} else {
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach $accountName.file.$endpointSuffix via port 445. Check your network configuration or consider using VPN or other tunneling options."
}

Output:
Testing connectivity to venkat326123.file.core.windows.net on port 445...
Connection successful! Proceeding with drive mapping...
Saving credentials...

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
Mapping drive Z to \\accountname.file.core.windows.net\share1...

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                                               ---------------
Z                   1.05     102398.95 FileSystem    \\accountname.file.core.windows...                                                                                                               
Drive mapped successfully! You can access it as Z:


Reference:
Mount Azure file share on Windows | Microsoft Learn
